# No Exception message being thrown

Tags: java, class, exception, coordinates

Hey I have a point class which generate a list of points.  The class is as follows

```
public class Point {

private double x, y;



public Point(double x, double y){

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

}//end constructor




public Point() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public double getX(){
        return x;
}

public void setX(double x) {
    try{ 
        if (x < 0){
            throw new NegArgumentException();
        }//end if
        else{
            this.x = x;

        }//end else
    }//end try
    catch (NegArgumentException e){
        System.out.println("error");
    }//end catch


}

public double getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(double y) {
    try{ 
        if (y < 0){
            throw new NegArgumentException();
        }//end if
        else{
            this.y = y;

        }//end else
    }//end try
    catch (NegArgumentException e){
        System.out.println("error");
    }//end catch

}

public String toString(){
    return "p(" + x + "," + y + ")";
}
}
```

I also created my own exception class NegArgumentException to throw an exception if a negative point is generated.

```
public class NegArgumentException extends Exception {


public NegArgumentException(){}

public NegArgumentException(String message){
    super(message);
}
```

}

I also have 2 other classes Rectangle and circle

```
public class Rectangle {
private Point upperLeft = new Point();
private Point lowerRight = new Point();


public Rectangle(Point upperLeft, Point lowerRight){
    this.upperLeft = upperLeft;
    this.lowerRight = lowerRight;

}//end constructor

public Point getUpperLeft() {
    return upperLeft;
}

public void setUpperLeft(Point upperLeft) {
    this.upperLeft = upperLeft;
}

public Point getLowerRight() {
    return lowerRight;
}

public void setLowerRight(Point lowerRight) {
    this.lowerRight = lowerRight;
}

public Point getUpperRight(){
    return new Point(getLowerRight().getX(), getUpperLeft().getY());
}

public Point getLowerLeft(){
    return new Point(getUpperLeft().getX(), getLowerRight().getY());
}


public double getArea(){
    return upperLeft.getX()*lowerRight.getY();
}

public String toString(){
    return "r[("+upperLeft.getX() + ","+upperLeft.getY()+"),("+lowerRight.getX()+","+lowerRight.getY()+")]";
}
}
```

And the Circle class

```
public class Circle {
private Point center = new Point();
private double radius;

public Circle(){}

public Circle(Point center, double radius){
    this.center = center;
    this.radius = radius;
}

public Point getCenter() {
    return center;
}

public void setCenter(Point center) {
    this.center = center;
}

public String toString(){
    return "c[("+center.getX()+","+center.getY()+"), "+ radius+"]";
}
}
```

My main class generates a random list of points for each of these objects.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //create arraylist for each class
    ArrayList<Point> list = new ArrayList<Point>();
    ArrayList<Rectangle> list1 = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
    ArrayList<Circle> list2 = new ArrayList<Circle>();
    //create random generators
    Random Point = new Random();
    Random myGenerator = new Random();
    int i = 0;
    //go through for loop
    while (i < 100){

        int whichArray = myGenerator.nextInt(4) + 1;
        //print out points for whichever random object
        if (whichArray == 1){
            int pointX = Point.nextInt(41) - 20;
            int pointY = Point.nextInt(41) - 20;
            if (pointX >= 0 && pointY >= 0){
            list.add(new Point(pointX, pointY));
            System.out.println(list.toString());
            list.remove(0);
            i++;
            }
        }//end if
        if (whichArray == 2){
            int pointX = Point.nextInt(41) - 20;
            int pointY = Point.nextInt(41) - 20;
            int pointRandom = Point.nextInt(20) - 20;
            if (pointX >= 0 && pointY >= 0 && pointRandom >= 0){
            list1.add(new Rectangle(new Point(pointX, pointY), new Point(pointX+pointRandom, pointY-pointRandom)));
            System.out.println(list1.toString());
            list1.remove(0);
            i++;
            }

        }//end if
        if (whichArray == 3){
            int pointX = Point.nextInt(41) - 20;
            int pointY = Point.nextInt(41) - 20;
            int radius = Point.nextInt(41) - 20;
            if (pointX >= 0 && pointY >= 0){
            list2.add(new Circle(new Point(pointX, pointY),radius));
            System.out.println(list2.toString());
            list2.remove(0);
            i++;
            }
        }//end if

    }//end while loop

}//end main


}//end class
```

The problem is that I do not see any message displayed from when an exception occurs.  I know it is working because I am getting no negative coordinates for my points.  Does anyone know why no message is being displayed?

Comment: When and why would an Exception occur? I see `if (pointX >= 0 && pointY >= 0)` guards everywhere!

Comment: well the thing is when i get rid of those, any number that wouldve been negative goes to 0 instead so my random coordinates has more 0's than it should @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Why not just the range you want to begin with?

Comment: I wish but my assignment specifically states to catch any negative numbers that appear @ElliottFrisch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the values of `Point` inside the constructor:

```
list.add(new Point(pointX, pointY));
```

So, setX and setY are never called, so, it is never verified if x and y are negatives.

Try something like this:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //create arraylist for each class
    ArrayList<Point> list = new ArrayList<Point>();
    ArrayList<Rectangle> list1 = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
    ArrayList<Circle> list2 = new ArrayList<Circle>();
    //create random generators
    Random Point = new Random();
    Random myGenerator = new Random();
    int i = 0;
    //go through for loop
    while (i < 100){
    int whichArray = myGenerator.nextInt(4) + 1;
    //print out points for whichever random object
    if (whichArray == 1){
        int pointX = Point.nextInt(41) - 20;
        int pointY = Point.nextInt(41) - 20;
        if (pointX >= 0 && pointY >= 0){
            Point point = new Point();
            point.setX(pointX);
            point.setY(pointY);
            list.add(point);
            System.out.println(list.toString());
            list.remove(0);
            i++;
        }
    }//end if
    if (whichArray == 2){
        int pointX = Point.nextInt(41) - 20;
        int pointY = Point.nextInt(41) - 20;
        int pointRandom = Point.nextInt(20) - 20;
        if (pointX >= 0 && pointY >= 0 && pointRandom >= 0){
            Point point = new Point();
            point.setX(pointX);
            point.setY(pointY);

            Point point2 = new Point();
            point2.setX(pointX+pointRandom);
            point2.setY(pointY-pointRandom);

            list1.add(new Rectangle(point, point2));
            System.out.println(list1.toString());
            list1.remove(0);
            i++;
        }

    }//end if
    if (whichArray == 3){
        int pointX = Point.nextInt(41) - 20;
        int pointY = Point.nextInt(41) - 20;
        int radius = Point.nextInt(41) - 20;
        if (pointX >= 0 && pointY >= 0){
        list2.add(new Circle(new Point(pointX, pointY),radius));
        System.out.println(list2.toString());
        list2.remove(0);
        i++;
        }
    }//end if

}//end while loop

}//end main


}//end class
```

This way, the verification will happen.

So, if for example, you change it to:

```
Point point = new Point();
point.setX(-1);
point.setY(-2);
list.add(point);
```

It will print:

```
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
[c[(17.0,10.0), 13.0]]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
[c[(20.0,6.0), 5.0]]
[c[(18.0,1.0), -18.0]]
[c[(18.0,20.0), 10.0]]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
[c[(20.0,19.0), 20.0]]
[c[(20.0,12.0), -14.0]]
[c[(2.0,20.0), 0.0]]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
[c[(10.0,13.0), 2.0]]
[c[(10.0,4.0), 15.0]]
[c[(20.0,7.0), 16.0]]
[c[(14.0,18.0), 2.0]]
[c[(20.0,8.0), 17.0]]
[c[(16.0,15.0), -13.0]]
[c[(7.0,6.0), 1.0]]
[c[(11.0,0.0), -15.0]]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
[c[(15.0,2.0), 20.0]]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
[c[(3.0,5.0), -7.0]]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
[c[(16.0,5.0), -10.0]]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
[c[(9.0,1.0), -3.0]]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
[c[(13.0,17.0), 7.0]]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
[c[(7.0,16.0), 14.0]]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
[c[(17.0,13.0), -5.0]]
[c[(14.0,8.0), 6.0]]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
[c[(13.0,0.0), 14.0]]
[c[(1.0,9.0), 2.0]]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
[c[(2.0,17.0), -1.0]]
[c[(17.0,8.0), -6.0]]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
[c[(7.0,19.0), -10.0]]
[c[(20.0,7.0), 3.0]]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
[c[(2.0,7.0), -10.0]]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
[c[(2.0,9.0), 14.0]]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
[c[(5.0,15.0), 18.0]]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
[c[(18.0,18.0), -5.0]]
[c[(6.0,2.0), -15.0]]
[c[(12.0,4.0), -3.0]]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
[c[(16.0,0.0), 20.0]]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
[c[(11.0,12.0), -19.0]]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
[c[(2.0,13.0), 13.0]]
[c[(20.0,2.0), 11.0]]
[c[(0.0,6.0), -10.0]]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
[c[(17.0,17.0), 7.0]]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
[c[(0.0,16.0), -11.0]]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
error
error
[p(0.0,0.0)]
[c[(14.0,4.0), -2.0]]
[c[(0.0,3.0), 11.0]]
[c[(11.0,15.0), -7.0]]
[c[(19.0,16.0), 19.0]]
[c[(8.0,13.0), 15.0]]
```

EDIT for the question: The problem is I can't get 0's in place of the negative coordinates. I need to get a positive number.

Change your Point class methods to this:

```
public void setX(double x) {
    try{ 
        if (x <= 0){
            throw new NegArgumentException();
        }//end if
        else{
            this.x = x;

        }//end else
    }//end try
    catch (NegArgumentException e){
        System.out.println("error");
    }//end catch

}
```

Look at: **x <= 0**. Same thing for `setY`.

Edited Again, to don't generate 0's, have a look at this code:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //create arraylist for each class
    ArrayList<Point> list = new ArrayList<Point>();
    ArrayList<Rectangle> list1 = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
    ArrayList<Circle> list2 = new ArrayList<Circle>();
    //create random generators
    Random randomNum = new Random();
    Random myGenerator = new Random();
    int i = 0;
    //go through for loop
    while (i < 100){

        int whichArray = myGenerator.nextInt(4) + 1;
        //print out points for whichever random object
        if (whichArray == 1){
            int pointX = 0;
            while (pointX == 0){
                pointX= randomNum.nextInt(41) - 20;
            }
            int pointY = 0;
            while(pointY == 0){
                pointY = randomNum.nextInt(41) - 20;
            }
            if (pointX >= 0 && pointY >= 0){
                Point point = new Point();
                point.setX(pointX);
                point.setY(pointY);
                list.add(point);
                System.out.println(list.toString());
                list.remove(0);
                i++;
            }
        }//end if
        if (whichArray == 2){
            int pointX = 0;
            while (pointX == 0){
                pointX= randomNum.nextInt(41) - 20;
            }
            int pointY = 0;
            while(pointY == 0){
                pointY = randomNum.nextInt(41) - 20;
            }
            int pointRandom = randomNum.nextInt(20) - 20;
            if (pointX >= 0 && pointY >= 0 && pointRandom >= 0){
                Point point = new Point();
                point.setX(pointX);
                point.setY(pointY);

                Point point2 = new Point();
                point2.setX(pointX+pointRandom);
                point2.setY(pointY-pointRandom);

                list1.add(new Rectangle(point, point2));
                System.out.println(list1.toString());
                list1.remove(0);
                i++;
            }

        }//end if
        if (whichArray == 3){
            int pointX = 0;
            while (pointX == 0){
                pointX= randomNum.nextInt(41) - 20;
            }
            int pointY = 0;
            while(pointY == 0){
                pointY = randomNum.nextInt(41) - 20;
            }
            int radius = randomNum.nextInt(41) - 20;
            if (pointX >= 0 && pointY >= 0){
            list2.add(new Circle(new Point(pointX, pointY),radius));
            System.out.println(list2.toString());
            list2.remove(0);
            i++;
            }
        }//end if

    }//end while loop

}//end main


}//end class
```

While it is 0, i will keep generating another random number.

Comment: When I do your method it says to is says the method is undefined for the type random. And when I try casting it, it says cannot cast.

Comment: The problem is I can't get 0's in place of the negative coordinates.  I need to get a positive number.

Comment: Edited again for you.

Comment: I really appreciate the help, but I am still getting an abnormal amount of 0's.  I think the problem might be that for each negative number that the random generator spits out, it is initializing those coordinates all to 0.  I need it to regenerate a new random coordinate until I get a positive number.

Comment: Ok, i understand now, i read the specification of Random.nextInt, it says "Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)" , so 0 can happen, i will try to help you out with it

Comment: Edited one more time.

Answer (score 3):

There are so many bad practices in your code that you should read something about writing clean code. By the way, no exception is thrown because your setter is never called. Change your constructor to

```
public Point(double x, double y) {    
    setX(x);
    setY(y);   
}
```

Plus, you always make sure that coordinates are positive with your `if` statements before creating your points, so there's no way a invalid `Point` can be instantiated.

Finally, even if it has nothing to do with your "problem", don't give a name starting with an upper case to a variable (your `Random` object), it is a bad practice for readability and even worse when it is also the name of a class. `Point.method()` could be ambiguous if `method` exists both in class `Point` and in class `Random`.